# Empty tag wikis show as "answered" by Community

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, community-user, tag-wiki-excerpt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tag wiki suggested edit show like answer suggested edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146674/tag-wiki-suggested-edit-show-like-answer-suggested-edit)

The timestamp for the original (empty) version of a tag wiki, or tag wiki excerpt shows that it's an **answer**.

[image: screenshot]

While this may be implemented as an answer in the backend, the message **should probably say nothing** here, since we can get the correct timestamp from the suggested edit on the right of the diff anyway.

Comment: +1: this has mildly annoyed me too, but not enough to write about it.

Comment: Tag wikis are just regular posts (`PostTypeId = 4` for summaries, `PostTypeId = 5` for the full text in Data.SE), and since they're not questions, they must *obviously* be answers.

Comment: It could also say _created_ instead of _answered_.