# Tag wiki suggested edit show like answer suggested edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, review

I've been reviewing at History SE and have found another bug in the system. This is a tag wiki excerpt suggested edit. However, it has a vote count on the left (I never knew you could vote for tags). Also, it says `answered 18 hours ago`. If tags get answers, I've been in the dark. However, this tag excerpt was *created* 18 hours ago. That's probably where it got the time.

[image: Bug screenshot]

This is sort of confusing. I think the system should display those points differently for tag wiki suggested edits (i.e., Remove vote count and change text to `created X hours ago`)

Comment: That says nothing about the vote count. I wonder why I couldn't find it, though.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about the vote, but for the rest is the same issue.

Comment: There were only two issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may have been broken forever, or in a recent view change as we plan for bigger things here...I'm not sure (and it's not worth investigating too much).

In either case, it'll show "created" in the next build for tag wikis, thanks for the report.

Comment: No suggested edits on tag wikis right now, so I can't see it. Does it still show the vote count?