# Random "Answered" on tag-wiki-excerpt revision

Tags: bug, revisions-list, tag-wiki-excerpt

Click the "link" icon ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12527224/3)) next to any revision in the history list for a tag excerpt ([e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12527224/revisions)), and note this:

> [image]

If you look closely enough, you can even see "Y Hello that" being rendered very faintly in the background.

Also, as Markdown isn't supported on excerpts, the markdown formatting (around `array_unique`) shouldn't be applied.

Comment: Thanks for splitting these out. :-)

Comment: I was still halfway through reading the original question, when I clicked one of the suggested edits (to find out I have a 7 day edit ban). What was it that I did wrong in adding this info to the tags - they were totally blank? I am confused? (It provided a link to the PHP function docs as well as the important bits of the syntax/paramters?)

Comment: @Fluffeh: You can visit each suggestion individually to find out why each was rejected (found by going to your profile and then clicking activity -> suggestions). The majority of them for rejected for plagiarizing content (stolen directly from php.net with no reference), and also for adding PHP wiki's for tags which weren't necessarily related to PHP.

Comment: @Fluffeh: Also, from your comment on the original post I deleted, it wasn't your actions per-se that made me uncover these bugs, it was me trying to improve [one of your edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review-beta/suggested-edits/682919) to add Markdown formatting to it

Comment: Okay, I can accept it (and follow the rules not to include content from the PHP docs) but I didn't think I was doing anything wrong by putting in basic syntax and params - should I just paraphrase in the future to add some basic info to these empty tags?

Comment: Probably related: [Empty tag wikis show as “answered” by Community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120082/empty-tag-wikis-show-as-answered-by-community)

Comment: @Fluffeh I rejected several of your tag wiki suggestions because you copied the documentation from one language, but the tag wasn't specific to that language. Having a tag wiki that says “this tag is about the PHP function” when more half the questions with that tag aren't about PHP is confusing. In addition, don't copy the documentation, as that usually violates the copyright of the documentation and is too much information. Write a short summary of what the function does and what language or framework it's form, and provide a link to the official documentation.

Comment: Man, this kept me thinking for a while. I couldn't find an answer from random anywhere...